Running MUI5 in remix("^2.9.1") issue
I want to run an app with recent version Remix and MUI5.
I searched like almost a week, but I cannot find any good answers.
When I run the app, the MUI button shows like 2~3 second and go back to normal button.
My current Node version is v20.11.1
I see error on the google chrome inspect:

Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Expected server HTML to contain a matching <meta> in <head>.
at meta
at head
at html
at Layout
occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in <#document>.

I installed latest version(today is (5/6/24)) remix(npx create-remix@latest) and MUI(npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled). I also added  "peerDependencies": {
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0"
},
in package.json
Here is my package.json, root.tsx, and _index.tsx
I have not touched any of entry.server.tsx and entry.client.tsx.
package.json:
{
  "name": "my-remix-app",
  "private": true,
  "sideEffects": false,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "remix vite:build",
    "dev": "remix vite:dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
    "start": "remix-serve ./build/server/index.js",
    "typecheck": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.16",
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.9.1",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.9.1",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^2.9.1",
    "isbot": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.9.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.4",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^5.1.0",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  }
}

root.tsx
import {
  Links,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
} from "@remix-run/react";

export function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        {children}
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return <Outlet />;
}

_index.tsx
import { Button, Typography } from "@mui/material";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <>
      <Typography>Text</Typography>
      <Button>click Me</Button>
    </>
  );
}

If you need more information, please let me know!

Those who need to struggle implementing MUI in Remix.run
You can search "react-canary". I think this solution is one of best one for now.
